# Howto properly parse response data received from GSM module?

Tags: c#, parsing, gsm, at-command, .net-micro-framework

I'm looking for some guidelines how to properly parse response data received from GSM module. I'm using uBlox SARA-G350. Documentation states:

```
Information responses:
<CR><LF><text><CR><LF>

Result codes:
<CR><LF><verbose code><CR><LF>

If the command line is successfully performed, the string "OK" (<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>)
is sent, otherwise "ERROR".
```

It might looks everything simple. We should read each sentence from `<CR><LF>` to `<CR><LF>` but...

- data may become in chunks
- response may contains doubled `<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>` (see example below)

Example - sms message sent to gsm module:

```
"Hi. Is IT
OK
"
```

After CMGL module respond (this is how end of sequence of returned data might looks like):

```
Hi. Is IT<CR><LF>
OK<CR><LF>
<CR><LF>
OK<CR><LF>
```

As you can see we have doubled `<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>`.

How do I know that I have whole sentence and should stop reading data from module and do parsing received data?

How AT parser should behave in situation like this?

Where I can find some guidelines how to properly parse incoming response data from gsm module?

Comment: Is it fixed that the code is always located at the end of the response? You could use a regular expression to parse the response.

Comment: Yes, it is fixed and i know which technique use but problem is in receiving whole data. I didn't know where is the end of sentence and when I should stop reading and do received data parsing. (i edit tags - .net micro, there is no regex)

Comment: Is it synchronous or aysnchronous?  Do you get unsolicited responses?

Comment: Yes I get unsolicited responses. I'm using SerialPort c# class with event for reading (so async) but in good practice is wait for OK/ERROR response after each AT command send so it will be rather sync. It can be done in fully async?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it. My bad assumption was that sms message can contain CrLf within. This is not true (at least for uBlox SARA-G350). All CrLf within some text received from module are replaced to Lf.

Thanks to that I can know that end of sentence will be when one of the next combinations arrives:

- `<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>`
- `<CR><LF>ERROR<CR><LF>`
- `<CR><LF> >`

The last one is prompt sign for sms sending command.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is interesting because the standards in large avoid saying what should happen if the text returned should contain something that resembles a *final result code*. [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) specifies in `5.7.3 Information text formats for test commands` only that the DCE should not generate false positives in breaking up long lines of response text, but does not explicitly forbid ever generating false positives... See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118) for related discussion around responses from `AT+CMGL`.

So to answer your question, you must assume this is implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. Suggested answer was very helpful. I find it earlier and this gives me idea to check again. Then I found my answer. :)