# send English SMS with GSM Modems (D-Link DWM-156)

Tags: c#, serial-port, sms

I am developing an application for GSM Modems (D-Link DWM-156) in C#.Net using AT commands. I have a problem sending English SMS.
 I try to send "hello", But I receive □□□□ in my phone or ...exept hello.

```
serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;

serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();


serialPort1.WriteLine("AT\r");
Thread.Sleep(2000);

serialPort1.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1\r");
Thread.Sleep(1000);

serialPort1.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"09390149196\"\r")
Thread.Sleep(2000);

serialPort1.WriteLine("hello" + "\x1A");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: What it shows on phone if you do serialPort1.WriteLine("123456" + "\x1A");
?

Comment: `WriteLine` outputs `\r` or `\r\n` anyway, no need to include them in the string

Comment: Garbled text usually means encoding/codepage problems. Are you able to send an SMS from the console using the same commands? Do you get 4 boxes or 5? 5 means an encoding problem, 4 means at least the last character was misinterpreted as a special character.

Comment: if I do serialPort1.WriteLine("123456" + "\x1A") .it shows on my phone s□IF<<U

Comment: I do this code but it does'nt work correct too.   serialPort1.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1\n");                      Thread.Sleep(1000);                       serialPort1.Write("AT+CMGS=\"09390149196\"\n");Thread.Sleep(1000);                                             serialPort1.Write("Hello" + "\x1A")

Comment: I send SMS with sim900. and I don't have any problem. but when I use D-Link DWM-156 I have this problem. plese help me!

Comment: Where are the sleep times taken from? Is there another way of knowing when we are ready to send another command?

Answer (score 1):

Few fixes (maybe more but I don't see full-code).

- Do not use `WriteLine()` but `Write()` because for `\r` (alone) is the command line and result code terminator character.
- `SerialPort.WriteLine()` by default writes a usASCII encoded string but your GSM modem expect strings encoded as specified with an AT command. Set `SerialPort.Encoding` property to a specific encoding and send `CSCS` command. You can *ask* supported encodings with `CSCS=?` AT command. Even if default GSM should apply I'd avoid to rely implicitly on this.
- You do not need to wait after each command but you have to wait for modem answer (checking for `OK` or `ERROR` strings).

From [docs](http://www.zoomtel.com/documentation/dial_up/100498D.pdf):

> A command line is made up of three elements: the prefix, the body, and the termination character. The command line prefix consists of the characters "AT" or "at" [...] The termination character may be selected by a user option (parameter S3), the default being CR.

In pseudo-code:

```
void SendCommand(string command) {
    serialPort.Write(command + "\r");

    // Do not put here an arbitrary wait, check modem's response
    // Reading from serial port (use timeout).
    CheckResponse();
}

serialPort.DataBits = 8;
serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();

SendCommand("AT"); // "Ping"
SendCommand("AT+CMGF=1"); // Message format
SendCommand("AT+CSCS=\"PCCP437\""); // Character set

SendCommand("AT+CMGS=\"123456\"") // Phone number
SendCommand("hello" + "\x1A"); // Message
```

To check response (absolutely avoid arbitrary waits!) you can start with something like this (raw untested adaption so you may need some debugging, see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/1207195)):

```
AutoResetEvent _receive;

string ReadResponse(int timeout)
{
    string response = string.Empty;

    while (true)
    {
        if (_receive.WaitOne(timeout, false))
        {
            response += _port.ReadExisting();
        }
        else
        {
            if (response.Length > 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Incomplete response.");
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No response.");
        }

        // Pretty raw implementation, I'm not even sure it covers
        // all cases, a better parsing would be appreciated here.
        // Also note I am assuming verbose V1 output with both \r and \n.
        if (response.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n"))
            break;

        if (response.EndsWith("\r\n> "))
            break;

        if (response.EndsWith("\r\nERROR\r\n"))
            break;
    }

    return response;
}
```

Adding `_receive.Reset()` just before you send your command and of course also adding `OnPortDataReceived` as handler for `SerialPort.DataReceived` event:

```
void OnPortDataReceived(object sender,
    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EventType == SerialData.Chars)
        _receive.Set();
}
```

If you have some trouble (but you can connect) you may replace `\r` with `\n`. Some modems *incorrectly* (assuming `<CR>` has not been mapped to anything else than `13` using `S3` parameter) use this character as command line terminator by default (even if it should be present in output only for `V1` verbose output). Either change your code or send appropriate `S3`.

Comment: thank you.but when I use your code I have before problem.when I send "h"(one character)  ,I receive correctly in my phone. but when 2 or more character for example "hello", ,I don't receive correctly in my phone.

Comment: Some modems (see at the end of updated answers) handle/accept/require \n INSTEAD OF \r (it's their _default_, you may specify what you want with S3 parameter). It's wrong (from _standard_ point of view) but you can try if it's your case. Just do not add \n, replace \r with \n in SendCommand() function.

Comment: Hi.i replace \r with \n  but I have before problem.

Comment: I do this code ever type.write with \n or \r and writeline with \n or \r. but none of them didn't do correctly.

Comment: What's modem response? Did you try to use \r and also specify S3=13?

Comment: yes.but when send "hello"( for example ) .it shows on my phone "e2□y". when I try this code with sim900 .it shows correct on my phone,but for GSM Modems (D-Link DWM-156) it does'nt show correct:-(