# AT Commands to Send SMS not working in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, at-command

I have been researching now for more than two days, trying to make an app to send SMS using AT Command, I implemented few tutorials and projects available on web. Unluckily, none of them worked.

[https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VfBbMcKZsutP8Cwg2iu7Rqiyccks1J6N2ZEbkbxnCTU/preview ] This code gives me Command executed, but message is not sent.

Then I tried another project (I am using C# and Visual Studio 2013), which have following files, After execution the status is changes to *Message Sent*, but I do not receive Message. I am using *HUAWEI Mobile Connect - 3G Application Interface* GSM Modem

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CSharp_SMS
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form_SMS_Sender());
    }
}
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CSharp_SMS
{
public partial class Form_SMS_Sender : Form
{
    private SerialPort _serialPort;
    public Form_SMS_Sender()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string number = textBoxNumber.Text;
        string message = textBoxMessage.Text;

        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM17", 19200);   //Replace "COM7" with corresponding port name

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Open();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + number + "\"\r\n");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Write(message + "\x1A");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        labelStatus.Text = "Status: Message sent";

        _serialPort.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Is there problem in the program? Did I missed any thing? Or, there's problem to run this in Windows 8.1, cause I also found that there is a program called MS HyperTerminal, which part of that is not clear to me.

Comment: That _tutorial_ should be deleted (related posts: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28315943/1207195) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/1207195)). What's not working? Any exception? Simply no result? You have to change some SerialPort properties, DO NOT WAIT using Thred.Sleep(), **check modem response** (BTW first sleep is useless). I'd also suggest to move that code to a backgroundworker (or you'll hang UI). Status is changed to "message sent" because it's what you write, what modem actually is telling you is unknown (because you're not reading its answer).

Comment: You made no authentication. Are you sure your SIM is without PIN?

HyperTerminal is used to directly send AT commands (whatever you enter is sent immediately.)

Comment: Run this with something like SysIntertnals Portmon running so you can see the responses from the device which you currently ignore completely  (look at issuing ATV1 / AT+CMEE commands to enable more detailed responses)

Comment: @IgorGorjanc I am Sure I donot have PIN for my SIM

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I tried changing SerialPort Properties. I'll surely go through exception handling now, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. I didn't knew anything about SysIntertnals Portmon, I'll surely use that now, hope I can find what I am missing here.

Comment: @LuzanBaral it's not about exception but modem response. After you send a command you have to wait for modem response. For some commands is absolutely mandatory, with sleep you won't read its messages (errors? OK?)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti So, how do I get to know about modem responses, please help me here

Comment: @LuzanBaral Read modem manual and general AT commands list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `AT Commands` in following format and it works.

```
public bool sendMsg(string smsid, string PhoneNo, string Message, string from, string to)
{
    string recievedData;
    bool isSend = false;
    string text = "Hello " + to + ",\n" + Message + "\n\n" + from;
    if (!port.IsOpen)                
        port = OpenPort();
    recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CMGF=1", 400, "Failed to set message format.");

    try
    {
        //string recievedData; // = ExecCommand(port, "AT", 3000, "No phone connected");
        String command = "AT+CMGS=\"" + PhoneNo + "\"";
        recievedData = ExecCommand(port, command, 1000, "Failed to accept phoneNo");
        command = text + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26) + "\r";
        recievedData = ExecCommand(port, command, 1000, "Failed to send message");
        if (recievedData.Contains("OK"))
        {
            isSend = true;                  
        }
        else if (recievedData.Contains("ERROR"))
        {
            isSend = false;                
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MyLog.Write(new LogPacket(ex, DateTime.Now));
    }
    return isSend;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [SMSPDUlib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15924/Library-for-Decode-Encode-SMS-PDU)

and code

```
    private const string LT = "\r\n";

    public void Auth(string pin)
    {
        lock (smsSendSync)
        {
            //Check if gateway is alive
            lastSplit = SplitResponse(SendCommand("AT"));
            if (!(lastSplit[lastSplit.Length - 1] == "OK"))
                throw new OperationCanceledException("AT connection failed");

            //Echo ON
            lastSplit = SplitResponse(SendCommand("ATE1"));
            if (!(lastSplit[lastSplit.Length - 1] == "OK"))
                throw new OperationCanceledException("ATE command failed");

            //Check echo
            lastSplit = SplitResponse(SendCommand("AT"));
            if (!(lastSplit.Length == 2 && lastSplit[1] == "OK"))
                throw new OperationCanceledException("AT command failed");

            //Verbose error reporting
            lastSplit = SplitResponse(SendCommand("AT+CMEE=2"));
            if (!(lastSplit.Length == 2 && lastSplit[1] == "OK"))
                throw new OperationCanceledException("AT+CMEE command failed");

            //Enter a PIN
            lastSplit = SplitResponse(SendCommand("AT+CPIN?"));
            if (!(lastSplit.Length == 3 && lastSplit[2] == "OK"))
                throw new OperationCanceledException("AT+CPIN? command failed");
            switch (lastSplit[1])
            {
                case "+CPIN: READY": //no need to enter PIN
                    break;
                case "+CPIN: SIM PIN": //PIN requested
                    lastSplit = SplitResponse(SendCommand("AT+CPIN=" + pin));
                    string m_receiveData = String.Empty;
                    WaitForResponse(out m_receiveData);
                    if (m_receiveData == String.Empty)
                        throw new OperationCanceledException("PIN authentification timed out");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new OperationCanceledException("Unknown PIN request");
            }
            //Check if registered to a GSM network
            lastSplit = SplitResponse(SendCommand("AT+CREG?"));
            if (!(lastSplit.Length == 3 && lastSplit[2] == "OK"))
                throw new OperationCanceledException("AT+CREG? command failed");
            lastSplit = lastSplit[1].Split(new string[] {" ", ","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (!(lastSplit[2] == "1" || lastSplit[2] == "5"))
                throw new OperationCanceledException("Not registered to a GSM network");
            Debug.WriteLine("Authentification successfull");
        }
    }

    private string[] SplitResponse(string response)
    {
        string[] split = response.Split(new string[] { LT }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
            split[i] = split[i].Trim();
        return split;
    }

    public string SendCommand(string command)
    {
        string m_receiveData = string.Empty;
        smsPort.ReadExisting();     //throw away any garbage
        smsPort.WriteLine(command + LT);
        WaitForResponse(out m_receiveData);
        //Debug.WriteLine(m_receiveData);
        return m_receiveData;
    }

    public string SendSms2(string phoneNumber, string message, bool flashMsg, SMS.SMSEncoding encoding)
    {
        if (phoneNumber.StartsWith("00"))
            phoneNumber = "+" + phoneNumber.Substring(2);
        if (phoneNumber.StartsWith("0"))
            //replace with your national code
            phoneNumber = "+386" + phoneNumber.Substring(1); 
        string StatusMessage = string.Empty;
        SMS sms = new SMS();                            //Compose PDU SMS
        sms.Direction = SMSDirection.Submited;          //Setting direction of sms
        sms.Flash = flashMsg;                           //Sets the flash property of SMS
        sms.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber.Replace(" ","");  //Set the recipient number
        sms.MessageEncoding = encoding;                 //Sets the Message encoding for this SMS
        sms.ValidityPeriod = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0, 0);  //Set validity period
        sms.Message = message;                          //Set the SMS Message text
        string sequence = sms.Compose() + CtrlZ;        //Compile PDU unit
        string sequenceLength = ((sequence.Length - 3) / 2).ToString();
        lock (smsSendSync)
        {
            StatusMessage = SendCommand("AT+CMGS=" + sequenceLength) + " ";
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            StatusMessage += SendCommand(sequence);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(StatusMessage);
        if (StatusMessage.Contains("ERROR"))
            throw new OperationCanceledException("Error sending SMS");
        return StatusMessage;
    }
```

Use `Auth()` to initialize modem and `SendSms2()` to send a SMS.

Comment: can you give summary of parameter passed like `flashMsg` and `encoding` on this function `public string SendSms2(string phoneNumber, string message, bool flashMsg, SMS.SMSEncoding encoding)`

Comment: FlashSMS:  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service#Flash_SMS  
Normally it should be false.  
  
Encoding:  
Encoding used to send SMS. It Can be _7bit, _8bit or UCS2 (something similar to Unicode)

Comment: Please do not use `Thread.Sleep` like that to wait for the `"\n\r> "` response from the modem. See the first part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118) for details.

Comment: I never run this on the main thread. I use `Task`, `Thread` or sth. similar for executing methods that involve I/O operations (and a `lock` to prevent possible concurrency problems). In this context `Thread.Sleep` works fine for me.
@hlovdal what do you suggest to use in this case instead of `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with which thread is running what. The point is that you **MUST** read and parse the response send back from the modem before seding the SMS payload.