# Sending SMS PDU mode error

Tags: c#, at-command

I tried to send sms using below command.

```
SmsCom.ExecCommand("AT+CMGS=42<CR>07915892000000F001000B915892214365F7000021493A283D0795C3F33C88FE06CDCB6E32885EC6D341EDF27C1E3E97E72E" + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26), 300, "Messagenot sent " + Portname + ".");
```

Is show this response with Error. Please kindly help me. Thanks

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: What error message is shown?

Comment: sorry for uncomplete info, just receive blank as response.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing this SmsCom library, I can guarantee that you cannot use ExecCommand (if it is implemented properly) to execute the `AT+CMGS` command. All other AT commands, but not that one. The reason is that you **MUST** wait for the `"\r\n> "` response before you send the payload. Anything else is a huge mistake that never will work reliable (if at all).

Start reading the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118) and then read chapter *4.3 Send Message +CMGS* in the 3GPP specification [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/270057.htm) to learn how to handle the AT+CMGS command properly. It is not the simplest AT command, but it is by all means doable with some care to its special required handling.