# How to know if you missed an incoming call in AT commands

Tags: serial-port, putty, at-command, modem

I am using Putty to simulate my phone's modem connected via serial. When my phone receives a call it outputs 'RING' into putty but when the caller cancel the call Putty doesn't out put any response or result.

How would the modem know that the caller disconnect/cancelled the call, but not output it in putty?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect missed calls you can try three things.

Check if there is a suitable `AT+CIND` indicator you can turn on. I do not think `call` will do since I assume it only goes to `1` when the call is answered. If your phone supports `callsetup` or something similar that should be what you need (you will have to implement logic to detect when a call does not go to state active).

For an example of enabling AT+CIND indicators, see chapter "8.57 Informative examples" in [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) for more explanation, and pay close attention to `The subparameter order in the command is defined by the query command order`, e.g.
if AT+CIND=? returns

```
+CIND: ("abc",(0-1)),("xyz",(0,1)),("call",(0,1))
```

then call is index 3, and for

```
+CIND: ("abc",(0-1)),("call",(0,1)),("xyz",(0,1))
```

call is index 2. Do **not** hard code any assumptions here, this should be parsed and checked run-time (one check at the beginning is enough).

---

Alternatively you can upon `RING` start polling call status with `AT+CLCC` until the call is no longer listed.

---

Or you could poll the `MC` phonebook storage and detect changes.

Comment: I used your second method. Every time my modem rings, I send the `AT+CLCC` and see if it returns something other than just `OK`. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Most modems show the incoming phone number and a `RING` when a call is received and an `END` when the call is cancelled. To view the missed calls, you may use the following `AT` Commands.

```
AT+CPBS="MC"
AT+CPBR=1,99
```

First command tells the modem to look in the missed call phone book and the second command loads entries from 1 to 99.  Note that this behavior is not standard. I was able to replicate this on a GSM module but not on my 3G modem. Try it on your modem and check if this works. All the best.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `MC` - missed calls - phonebook storage is in every way possible standard. However, the number of entries, e.g. 99, is completely manufacturer specific (and strictly speaking MC is only a `defined` storage value of AT+CPBR, and not specifically mandatory. However in practice absolutely all mobile phone manufactures supports this, but perhaps hardware dongles made by companies that do not also make mobile phones have a less sensible subset of supported standard AT commands? There exists zero good reasons for not supporting `MC` today though (and hardly did in early 90s)).

Comment: To find out which phonebook storages are supported and how many entries they support see the last example in chapter "8.57 Informative examples" in the [27.007 standard](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) which both gives the commands and explains them.

Comment: Regarding the `END` result code this is not standard at al, there are no references to it in neither V.250 nor 27.007. The closest thing would be the `NO CARRIER` [double final result code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118) for voice calls initiated with ATD, but that is then not for incoming calls.

Comment: Thank you for your response. :)