# Is there a specific string format to implement "Ctrl + Z" action for AT Command?

Tags: kotlin, at-command

I'm trying to send a SMS using AT command and I need to execute "Ctrl + Z" action after writing the message content.

I tried using the "x1A" and "u001A" but they're not working.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
"AT+CMGS=\"$phoneNumber\"\r\n$message\\x1A"
```

To add more information I'm trying to automate the procedure of sending SMS in quectel modem:

AT+CMGS=[,]
text is specified
<Ctrl+Z/ESC>

I want to send "Ctrl+Z" by command not pressing the keys.

Comment: What are you trying to do.. Undo the message? With what you posted it's unclear of what your trying to do. Add more code so we can see the bigger picture and explain what your trying to do

Comment: I know the commands I am just trying to figure how your calling the end text portion... There is not enough code to go on

Comment: <Ctrl+z> this is usually what's used, but you said that did not work, correct?

Comment: What I need is a one line command to do the "Ctrl+z" action by not pressing the keys.

Comment: the first thing logically would be to set up and invoke the keyboard key like you would do in c#. However, when it comes to the Android keyboard that’s a whole different ball game. I don’t know the keycodes for the android keyboard. If you find the keycodes for android keyboard you could possibly simulate the key combo. But this is what I have found docs wise..  https://www.developershome.com/sms/cmgsCommand.asp it explains the entire setup maybe you can decipher it

Answer (score 1):

Strictly answering your question, the function for concatenating `CTRL+Z` character to the AT command string is `toChar()`:

```
var testString = "test" + 0x1A.toChar()
```

Anyway this will not work because the AT command you are using is not correct.

`+CMGS` command, in text mode, only the destination number is passed as a parameter. The message has to be sent after the *prompt* `>` is received from the modem. So:

1. Make sure to switch to text mode (default is PDU mode)

   ```
    AT+CMGF=1
   ```
2. Send `+CMGS` command and wait for the prompt

   ```
    AT+CMGS=xxxyyyzzz
    >
   ```
3. Send the actual message appending the text terminator as explained above

Design your program accordingly.

Comment: Spot on answer. For details/reasoning why waiting for the prompt before sending the payload is important, see the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118).